# Getting 403 Forbidden using AWS PHP SDK to perform API Gateway getConnection or postToConnection (works in Postman)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to write some PHP code to post a message to an AWS API Gateway, using the AWS SDK.  This is the code I have written (with fake credentials in place of the real ones solely for this question of course):

```
require_once('/aws/aws-autoloader.php');

$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('AWSACCESSKEY', 'AWSSECRETKEYGOESHERE');
$client = new \Aws\ApiGatewayManagementApi\ApiGatewayManagementApiClient([
    'endpoint'    => 'https://q1w2e3r4t5y.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing',
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
$val = $client->postToConnection(array('ConnectionId' => 'NC0nN3cT10N1d=', 'Data' => 'Hello World'));
var_dump($val);
```

But when I execute this code I'm getting this error in my logs:

```
2020/05/25 16:14:14 [error] 19787#19787: *20652052 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal 
error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\ApiGatewayManagementApi\Exception\ApiGatewayManagementApiException' 
with message 'Error executing "PostToConnection" on 
"https://q1w2e3r4t5y.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/@connections/NC0nN3cT10N1d%3D"; 
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST 
https://q1w2e3r4t5y.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/@connections/NC0nN3cT10N1d%3D` 
resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
{"message":"Forbidden"}
ForbiddenException (client): Forbidden - {"message":"Forbidden"}'
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST 
https://q1w2e3r4t5y.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/@connections/NC0nN3cT10N1d%3D` 
resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
{"message":"Forbidden"}
 in /var/www/html/project/aws/GuzzleHttp/Exception/RequestException.php:113
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/project/aws/GuzzleHttp/Middleware.php(65): 
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 
Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /var/w" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.39.215, server: example.com, 
request: "GET /tmp/debug.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", 
host: "example.com"
```

Here are the same settings used in Postman with success:
[image]

When I send that in Postman I get a 200 OK and I see whatever I put in the body appear in my websocket listener (I'm using this Chrome Extension to create and listen to a connection: [Simple WebSocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo?hl=en)).

So I know the IAM user credentials are correct, but for some reason it's like the AWS PHP SDK isn't signing the request correctly.  If I remove the `postToConnection` call I do NOT get the error, so I know it's not failing on generating the client itself.

What am I missing?  Why does this work in Postman and not in the AWS PHP SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the endpoint needs to end with a trailing `/` after the stage.

So this line of PHP:

```
'endpoint'    => 'https://q1w2e3r4t5y.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing',
```

becomes

```
'endpoint'    => 'https://q1w2e3r4t5y.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testing/',
```

And that's it.

The lesson: Holy crap AWS's error messages are horrible...